# Celery - How to use Chunks in Chord?

Tags: python-3.x, celery

Is it possible to run the tasks inside chord() as chunks? Currently I have a chord implementation which works fine for smaller list of tasks but for larger tasks it ends up creating 40k - 50k tasks. I want to prevent that since it seems to be working inefficiently, especially at the end when it's trying to collect all the results.

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019022/5918981 but it didn't work for me. Also tried adding callback inside `apply_async()` of `task_name.chunks().apply_async()` as an alternative, but that gives me this error: "Cannot add link to group: use a chord".

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for why the callback couldn't be added directly to the chunks call but this sample code worked for me in a similar situation. **Most important is that I converted the chunks to a group**.

```
def handle_name(name):
    data = {}
    # handle name
    return data

def do_stuff_callback(results):
    # results will have the following structure in this case: [[{},{}],[{},{}],....]
    pass

def do_stuff():
    chunk_size = 2  # dummy value
    names = [......]  # a very big list
    tasks = [handle_name.chunks(names, chunk_size).group()]
    chord(tasks)(do_stuff_callback.s())
```